# change TCP_TIMEWAIT_LEN at runtime

Tags: linux, networking, sysctl, tcp-ip

Linux kernel defines a timeout to destroy `TIME-WAIT` state of a connection in `include/net/tcp.h`:

```
#define TCP_TIMEWAIT_LEN (60*HZ)
```

Is there a way to change this parameter at runtime, via `sysctl` or `/proc` entry, or may be running `ip` utility from `iproute2`?

Comment: That is not a tunable value, see this article https://vincent.bernat.im/en/blog/2014-tcp-time-wait-state-linux.html .   What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: That article actually says it is definitely tunable just that if you think you might need to tune it then you don't need to be tuning it.

Comment: That is a good read though, thanks for the link.